# Woocomerce API internal server error when adding order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, server-error

I am developing a online store with React-Native, which allows customers to purchase products.
I am using the [woocomerce API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#introduction), a Wordpress plugin.

When I try to create an order from the API, it gives me an internal server error.

Here is my API call to create an order :

```js
const data = {
        payment_method: "mollie_wc_gateway_creditcard",
        payment_method_title: "Mollie - Carte de crédit",
        set_paid: false,
        billing: {
          first_name: "John",
          last_name: "Doe",
          address_1: "1 rue des champs",
          address_2: "",
          city: "Paris",
          state: "FR",
          postcode: "75000",
          country: "FR",
          email: "john.doe@example.com",
          phone: "0636......"
        },
        shipping: {
            first_name: "John",
            last_name: "Doe",
            address_1: "1 rue des champs",
            address_2: "",
            city: "Paris",
            state: "FR",
            postcode: "75000",
            country: "FR",
            email: "john.doe@example.com",
            phone: "0636......"
        },
        line_items: [
          {
            product_id: 3884,
            quantity: 2
          },
          {
            product_id: 3198,
            variation_id: 3375,
            quantity: 1
          }
        ],
        shipping_lines: [
          {
            method_id: "lpc_sign",
            method_title: "Colissimo avec signature",
            total: "6.70"
          }
        ]
      };

    return await api.post('orders', data).then((response)=>response);
```

I want to create an order with two products and with "Colisimo avec signature" delivery method.

And here is the response :

```json
{
   "additional_errors": [], 
   "code": "internal_server_error", 
   "data": {
      "status": 500
   }, 
   "message": "<p>There was a critical error on this site.</p><p><a 
               href=\"https://fr.wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/\">Learn
               more on debugging WordPress.</a></p>"
}
```

I checked in the woocommerce logs and found this error :

```
2021-02-09T01:21:04-08:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function __isset() on null in /homepages/17/d837071568/htdocs/clickandbuilds/LyoncapsEcommerce/wp-content/plugins/tshirtecommerce/tshirtecommerce.php:1114
Stack trace:
#0 /homepages/17/d837071568/htdocs/clickandbuilds/LyoncapsEcommerce/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): tshirt_order_meta_handler(64, NULL, NULL)
#1 /homepages/17/d837071568/htdocs/clickandbuilds/LyoncapsEcommerce/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#2 /homepages/17/d837071568/htdocs/clickandbuilds/LyoncapsEcommerce/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /homepages/17/d837071568/htdocs/clickandbuilds/LyoncapsEcommerce/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-deprecated-action-hooks.php(159): do_action('woocommerce_add...', 64, NULL, NULL)
#4 /homepages/17/d837071568/htdocs/clickandbuilds/LyoncapsEcommerce/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-deprecated-action-hooks.php(107): WC_Deprecated_Action_Hooks->trigger_hook('woocommerce_add...', Arr dans /homepages/17/d837071568/htdocs/clickandbuilds/LyoncapsEcommerce/wp-content/plugins/tshirtecommerce/tshirtecommerce.php at line 1114
```

Note that the order has been created but information such as the 2nd product and the delivery method are missing.

[image: Created order]
Sorry but it's in french. Im french, so sorry for my english ^^

I noticed that the products with variations (color, size ...) are missing. Even if I don't choose a product with variations, I get the same error.

I don't know how to fix this problem. I absolutely need to solve this problem quickly because my deadline is in 1 month.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just another Wordpress plugin (Woocommerce Custom Product Designer) that interferes whith the API. I disabled this plugin and now it work!